# Primefaces OutputPanel deffered loading use wrong url for ajax call

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Application / Environement Setup:
JSF 2.2 (Mojarra)
Primefaces v 7.0.0 (03.2019)
Component p:outputPanel with deffered loading

What we expect is that the xhr request will be send to the same URL (service) where the component is embedded (used).

Let's assume the url where the component is used is: https://www.example.com/ad/product_123

The xhr call is not send to the above url, instead its going to https://www.example.com/search.jsf.

Inside the xhtml page we use a plain html form in the header for user search inputs. I guess, that the javascript function, which collecting the url for the xhr call is grabbing the wrong url?

how can i verify where the primefaces p:outputPanel component with deffered=true is grabing the url, which will be used called?

example xhr

```
{"Formulardaten":{"javax.faces.partial.ajax":"true","javax.faces.source":"j_idt182","primefaces.ignoreautoupdate":"true","javax.faces.partial.execute":"j_idt182","javax.faces.partial.render":"j_idt182","j_idt182":"j_idt182","j_idt182_load":"true","search":""}}
```

as you can the inside the xhr request, it is involving a parameter 'search' which we declared in our plain html form. 
Thanks

Comment: What if you add the panel into a `h:form` as it is done in the [showcase](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panel/outputPanel.xhtml)?

Comment: I would expect it to use what is on the html form element in the browser, so check there

Comment: works, many thanks @Selaron. Some times, day is too long...